# How do I change the back up dancers' choreography in Dance Central?

Tags: dance-central, dance-central-3

[Here's an example of what I'm talking about](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8r1VpQuPoY). At first, I thought it had something to do with the song being DLC, but when I purchased the song, their choreography didn't change. I looked at the options, but I can't find any option allowing me to change the back up dancers' choreography. It looks pretty cool, so I want to know how to do it for my own games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a controller for this. first choose different difficulty then press ready for 2nd character and then press start with main character